# how to make React native get the notification when the app is killed

Tags: react-native

Thanks for help.

I have an idea.

obj-c processes notification and pass the content to rn.

And I will try this.

Comment: why do you need to know this? (What's the use-case)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do anything after the app is killed (because it's killed !).

What you can observe though is when the app goes in background / get back focus. See AppState API in React Native. http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html#content

Comment: In Obj-c with a third-lib-sdk for PushNotification,I try to notice the killed ReactNative app when Obj-c get notification and then open a new page.